# How to get offset position of a text in html page in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am doing a webscraping to extract some text using beautiful soup.

I am successfully extracting the required text from the webpage but my new requirement is along with the text I need to extract the offset number/position where the text actually started and ended in the document.

Is there any possibility for this using beautiful soup or any helpful packages for this ?

Please provide your thoughts and suggestions...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following code

```
import re

DATA = "This is test message"

for match in re.finditer(r'(?s)((?:[^\n][\n]?)+)', DATA):
    print match.start(), match.end()
```

Output

0 20